# How to create cursor using for loop in PL/SQL to transfer records?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

For creating cursor using FOR loop, but my only problem is how can we transfer each row that has been fetch into another table ? Is it possible?

Using blocks of PL/SQL and include a FOR loop of sequel after we fetch rows from specific table and after that we would like to transfer the rows that has been fetch to the other tables.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use `PL/SQL` and `CURSOR` here?  This seems like it could be solved with a simple `INSERT INTO....SELECT` statement.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with how to do this, here is an example from the Oracle Documentation ([Documentation Link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2126076))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which *copies* values from Scott's `DEPT` table into `TEST` table (owned by Scott as well).

```
SQL> create table test (deptno number, dname varchar2(20), loc varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select deptno, dname, loc
  3                  from dept
  4                  where deptno <= 30
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      insert into test (deptno, dname, loc)
  8        values (cur_r.deptno, cur_r.dname, cur_r.loc);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO

SQL>
```